# Abandoned cart marketing automation campaign not working

Tags: sitecore-commerce, marketing-automation

We are using OOTB abandoned cart marketing automation campaign for our `Experience Commerce(XC)` based website. Already installed the `Abandoned Cart Campaign Site Setup` module for our site node in the content editor and deployed all the marketing definitions. We have created and activated an email in the site-specific EXM editor using the abandoned cart email template and assigned this email in the marketing automation.

Now, on our website, when a user logs in and adds a sellable item to the cart and leaves the page, We can see marketing automation workflow gets triggered but contacts are getting stuck at the custom listener step (`where the contact's cart has been manipulated`) as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

These are the error from the logs:

```
[Error] An error occurred during activity invocation for activity '622086f9-cba2-8b7c-cac0-3721340e0319' in plan '6624497c-e642-4d86-b106-befb12532ef9'
DescriptorId : 47134e14-c9ff-4c9a-816d-7cfd92e7616d
Sitecore.XConnect.Segmentation.ExpressionBuilder.PredicateDescriptorException: No predicate descriptor was registered with Id '47134e14-c9ff-4c9a-816d-7cfd92e7616d'.
```

I checked the predicate ID which is mentioned in the logs `47134e14-c9ff-4c9a-816d-7cfd92e7616d` is already available in content editor:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by performing below steps:

1. Copy `<sitecore_root>\bin\Sitecore.Commerce.Connect.Collection.Model.dll` file to your `<xConnect_root>\bin` folder.
2. Copy `<sitecore_root>\XConnectFiles\Configs\sc.XConnect.Collection.Model.Commerce.Plugins.xml` file to `<xConnect_root>\App_Data\Config\Sitecore\Collection` folder.
3. Copy `<sitecore_root>\XConnectFiles\Configs\sc.XConnect.Segmentation.Commerce.Predicates.xml` file to `<xConnect_root>\App_Data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\App_Data\Config\sitecore\Segmentation` folder.
4. Navigate to the Sitecore Experience Commerce installation package. You can download it from [here](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Commerce/93/Sitecore_Experience_Commerce_93_Initial_Release.aspx).
5. Copy the files from the `Sitecore Commerce Marketing Automation for AutomationEngine 14.0.27.zip` archive to your Marketing Automation folder (`<xConnect_root>\App_Data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine`). Please make sure to follow the same folders structure as in the zip archive.
6. You may also need to restart the Marketing Automation engine service after that.

After Marketing Automation restart, new enrolled contacts were not getting stuck in MA workflow, and no errors in the logs.